# KDE 4 opens up the items that were not closed at shutdown again

Tags: kubuntu, startup, shutdown, startup-applications

Let's say i have Chromium and Dolphin open up when I shut down, then both are reopen upon reboot.How do I prevent this ?

DWM : KDE 4

Linux flavour : Ubuntu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`System Settings` > `Advanded` > `Session manager`

There should be a setting for `start with an empty session`.

[image]